# Parse Json Day- and Time-String to a Case Class with Date in PlayFramework 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

In PlayFramework 2.1 I want to read a json and create a case class. The structure is different, so I cannot use the default reader. What do I have to write to merge the both Strings to the java.util.Date?

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.util._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._

case class Person(name: String, lastSeen: Date)
val jsonString = Json.parse("""{name: "Joe", day: "2013-03-28", time: "09:35"}""")

val personLastSeen: Reads[Person] = (
  (__ \ "name").read[String] ~
  // (__ \ "day").read[String] (__ \ "time").read[String] // @TODO
)(Person)
```

Should I swap this read? I tried `val dateStructure = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")` with `dateStructure.parse(...)` but I think I need a `Reads[Date]` there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you cannot do this using Reads[T] combinators but you can define a trait Reads and its method `def read(json: JsValue): JsResult[T]`

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.util._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

case class Person(name: String, lastSeen: Date) {      
}

object Person {
  implicit val personLastSeen = new Reads[Person] {
    val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[Person] = {
      JsSuccess(Person(
        (js \ "name").as[String],
        sdf.parse((js \ "day").as[String] + " " + (js \ "time").as[Float])))
    }
  }
}
object Test extends App {
    val jsonString = Json.parse("""{name: "Joe", day: "2013-03-28", time: "09:35"}""")
}
```